# Correspondence between variational method and Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, feynman-diagrams, many-body

There are two ways to look at the Hartree or Hartree-Fock equations. One method relies on the variational method for a particular type of the probe function and the second one originates from summation of some type of Feynman diagrams.

Other widely known approximate methods constitute of e.q. Random phase approximation (RPA) or Ladder approximation (LA). I am wondering if there is a straightforward connection between variational method and perturbative series? In particular if one can 'justify' Gutzwiller ansatz [link](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Gutzwiller_wave_function) by summation of some type of Feynman diagrams?